# How can I attach a cover panel to the bottom of my cabinetry?

Tags: cabinets

[image]

I have these wall cabinets and I want to hide the bottom of the cabinet and cover it with nice surface.

I am thinking to install thin (7/16) OSB board and stick [**wall paper**](https://a.co/d/djTw2VQ) over it, let me know if that would work.

My question is, how can I apply thin OSB board to cabinet, can I screw it to the cabinet frame or I need thicker board?

Purpose is just to cover it, not for load bearing. So thin OSB would work but how can I screw thin board? How to hide screws ? Any other ideas to attach it without screws? I need ideas/suggestions.

Comment: If by "work" you mean "make it an actual active eyesore, rather than an unremarkable bit of cabinetry that doesn't look that bad" yup, it will achieve that in spades.

Comment: How often do you see the bottom of these particular cabinets that you're willing to go to the effort of hiding the bottoms? Sure, you'll looking at them now during the install, but you might consider waiting to see how often you notice them during actual "use" before doing any more work to them. This is the normal state that cabinets are left in and very few people have issue with it. Of course, if they're installed high on a wall in a room where you're normally seated, it may well be worth the extra effort.

Comment: Of course, if you do decide to go ahead with this, you'll be back here asking how to hide the edge of the 7/16" OSB (or even plywood) because you'll be adding an extra layer of ugly that you'll then want to hide...

Comment: Just an observation: You'd be giving up a recess that makes a nice place to put a flat counter-light fixture.

Answer (score 8):

7/16" OSB + wallpaper seems like a lot of work.

I would try to find plywood that has a finish you are reasonably OK with and use it plain. Just cut and screw or nail into place and you're done. Something like [this 1/8" x 4' x 8' utility panel from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Utility-Panel-Common-1-8-in-x-4-ft-x-8-ft-Actual-0-106-in-x-48-in-x-96-in-833096/100543684):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

OSB has an irregular surface, and edge, texture, you'll need to fill that before you paper it.

Some other options:

- Plywood, MDF, or hardboard pre-finished wall paneling.  Just glue and tack it in place, put some trim on the exposed edge.
- 1/8" plywood, MDF, or Hardboard (painted or papered)
- drywall could work too.